# @OneToOne annotoation problem (i think...)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, one-to-one

im new in hibernate and JPA and i have some problems with annotations.

My target is to create this table in db (PERSON_TABLE with personal-details)

```
ID      ADDRESS     NAME    SURNAME     MUNICIPALITY_ID
```

First of all, i have a MUNICIPALITY table in db containing all municipality of my country.
I mapped this table in this ENTITY:

```
@Entity
public class Municipality implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String country;
private String province;
private String name;
@Column(name="cod_catasto")
private String codCatastale;
private String cap;


public Municipality() {
}

...
```

Then i make an EMBEDDABLE class Address containing fields that realize a simple address...

```
@Embeddable
public class Address implements Serializable {

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="id_municipality")
private Municipality municipality;
@Column(length=45)
private String address;

public Address() {
}

...
```

Finally i embedded this class into Person ENTITY

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String surname;
@Embedded
private Address address;

public Person() {
}

...
```

All works good when i have to save a new Person record, in fact hibernate creates a PERSON_TABLE as i want, but if i try to retrieve a Person record i have an exception.
HQL is simply "from Person"
The excpetion is (Entities is the package containing all classes above-mentioned):

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on Entities.Person.address.municipality references an unknown entity: Entities.Municipality
```

Is the @OneToOne annotation the problem?

My hibernate.cfg.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/DB_PATH</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="Entities.Person"/>
        <mapping class="Entities.Municipality"/>
        <mapping class="Entities.Address"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is... i lunch my querys into netbeans "HQL Query()" tab, i try to create a query

```
session.createQuery("from Person");
```

and all works good.

Sorry guys my fault, i do this test first... i thought that HQL wizard into netbeans was a reliable tool to test queries...

In this case, wich of answer i have to choice? All are reasonable and full of tips!

Sorry again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. At least, you have provided what happened (+1)

Answer (score 2):

**I suppose** your error is just because you have defined a @Embeddable class (Address) as Entity. @Embeddable class **is not a plain** Entity, so remove it from your hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<mapping class="Entities.Person"/>
<mapping class="Entities.Municipality"/>
```

Comment: +1 - I was writing exactly the same when I saw this post.  Don't know that it fixes this, but it's an error.

Comment: Yes is reasonable, but the problem stay.

Comment: The code is the same i have posted, exept i have setter and getter obviusly.

Answer (score 1):

No. The problem is that Hibernate does not recognize `Municipality` as an entity. Is it configured properly (e.g. in your persistence.xml)?

*Edit:* The error message is weird for this situation, and I don't know if that is really the problem, but `Address.municipality` should be defined as `@ManyToOne` (as there will be multiple addresses referencing the same municipality).

Comment: @blow: That looks fine. What happens when you query "from Municipality"?

Comment: "from Municipality" works good, retrieve a list of all my Municipality.
The problem may be that i have an @entity(Municipality) associate @OneToOne to an @emebddable(Address) embedded into an @entity(Person) and not directly to Person?

Comment: Thank you, i tried to change @OneToOne in @ManyToOne but problem rest.

Maybe i have to add some association in Municipality too?
I tried this in Municipality:

@OneToMany
private List<Address> addresList;

The problem stay...

Answer (score 1):

Are you damn sure you use `@javax.persistence.Entity` instead of `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`?

OK, another guess. Could you try changing the `@OneToOne` to `@OneToOne(targetEntity = Municipality.class)`?

Comment: Sure, my imports are this:

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;